# Changing service startup order

Tags: networking, centos, boot, services, init

I use wpa_supplicant to configure the wireless connection. Now I have a problem in that the network service starts before wpa_supplicant so this happens:

```
Bringing up interface wlan0:  
Determining IP information for wlan0... failed; no link present.  Check cable?
```

When I after that restart the network service the wireless connection then gets an IP and works.

I was reading about altering the start order by changing the the start order number in the respective init script. This is it in wpa_suplicant:

```
# chkconfig:   - 23 88
```

And this is it in network:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 10 90
```

So if I understand correctly I could change the 23 to 9 and it would start before. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me; you can always try, and change it back if it breaks something else.

Comment: What version of CentOS? CentOS 6 has `upstart` which can handle this much more easily.

Comment: @jordanm Centos 6 I will search for it. Could you post an answer about it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change the boot priority but it didn't work. There is a bug:

http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5794

So the solution was to give up on `dhcp` and set the address static in `ifcfg-wlan0`